# I need to set up mail forwarding on debian server

Tags: email, debian-squeeze, redirection

I have a new Debian squeeze VPS with which I'm using to serve a couple of web sites. I have an email address me@mydomain.com that I would like to redirect to me@gmail.com.

Can I install some script or service to do that? If so what would suit my needs best. I did some looking around already and found sendmail but that looks too complex and nullmailer but I'm not sure if that would work for this scenario.

Comment: Which MTA server do you use? [sendmail/postfix/exim/...]

Comment: None yet. That's the point. I wanted to know which one to install. But I actually just managed to get it working using postfix by following these instructions: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-postfix-forward-email-to-another-account/

Answer (score 0):

I use `Exim4` which should be available as a package.  Configuration can mostly be done with `dpkg-reconfigure`.  Once it is installed add the appropriate alias to `/etc/aliases`.

You likely want to configure using a `smarthost` (mail relay).  You will need to decide if you want any local email, or want to send all messages to your `gmail` account.

Either `postfix` or `sendmail` should be just about as easy to configure.